# Process to go from a recurrence to a closed formula.

Tags: combinatorics

Given the following recurrence: a,b,c are natural numbers.

P(a,b,c)=PA(a,b,c)+PB(a,b,c)+PC(a,b,c)

Where

PA(a,b,c)=0 if a=0

PA(a,b,c)=1 if (a,b,c) = (1,0,0)

PA(a,b,c)= PB(a-1,b,c)+PC(a-1,b,c)

PB(a,b,c)=0 if b=0

PB(a,b,c)=1 if (a,b,c) = (0,1,0)

PB(a,b,c)= PA(a,b-1,c)+PC(a,b-1,c)

PC(a,b,c)=0 if c=0

PC(a,b,c)=1 if (a,b,c) = (0,0,1)

PC(a,b,c)= PA(a,b,c-1)+PB(a,b,c-1)

Which would be the process to get a closed formula? Non recurrence?

Thanks!
Enric

Comment: Generating functions?

Comment: Could be generating functions... How?

Comment: Define $F_A(x,y,z) = \sum_{a=0}^\infty \sum_{b=0}^\infty \sum_{c=0}^\infty P_A(a,b,c) x^a y^b z^c$ and similarly for $F_B$ and $F_C$, and use the given recursive identities to get functional identities among $F_A,F_B,F_C$, which hopefully allow you to identify those functions and hence their coefficients.